# How to not print duplicate lines from an external text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a multiple choice quiz using python. I have an external .txt file that has 20 questions in and I want it to select 10 random questions from that file, which it currently does. The file has the layout:

1,Who was the first man to walk on the moon?,A.Michael Jackson,B.Buzz Lightyear,C.Neil Armstrong,D.Nobody,C

The problem i'm having is that I don't want it to print the same question twice.

The only way I can think to solve this is to add detail[0], which is the question number, to a list defined in python and then check within that list to make sure that the question number isn't duplicated.

```py
import random
qno = []
def quiz():
    i = 0
    global score #makes the score variable global so it can be used outside of the function
    score=0 #defines the score variable as '0'
    for i in range (1,11): #creates a loop that makes the program print 10 questions
        quiz=open('space_quiz_test.txt').read().splitlines() #opens the file containing the questions, reads it and then splits the lines to make them seperate entities
        question=random.choice(quiz)
        detail = question.split(",")
        print(detail[0],detail[1],detail[2],detail[3],detail[4],detail[5])
        print(" ")
        qno.append(detail[0])
        print(qno)
        if detail[0] in qno is False:
            continue
            qno.append(detail[0])
            print(qno)
        elif detail[0] in qno is True:
            if detail[0] not in qno == True:
                print(detail[0],detail[1],detail[2],detail[3],detail[4],detail[5]) 
                print(" ")
                qno.append(detail[0])
                print(qno)
        while True:
            answer=input("Answer: ")
            if answer.upper() not in ('A','B','C','D'):
                print("Answer not valid, try again")
            else:
                break
        if answer.upper() == detail[6]:
            print("Well done, that's correct!")
            score=score + 1
            print(score)
            continue
        elif answer.upper() != detail[6]:
            print("Incorrect, the correct answer is ",detail[6])
            print(score)
            continue

quiz()
```

When I run this code I expect that no question is repeated twice but it always seems to do that, i'm struggling to think of a way to do this. Any help would be grateful, Thank you!

Comment: Hi Milan, you may not be familiar with the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable] example aspect of asking questions since you are new, but your question is pretty good. The part is misses is "Minimal." You whole code is really necessary to ask the question you had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
questions = random.sample(quiz, 10)
```

It will select a random sublist of length 10, from the quiz list.

Also:

You should read the file, and make the question list outside the loop, then just loop over the questions:

```
with open('space_quiz_test.txt') as f:
    quiz = f.readlines()

questions = random.sample(quiz, 10)
for question in questions:
    ...
```

Comment: wow ... why did I specify `k=` all the time ... it works without

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, it isn't giving me any duplicate questions which is good. The problem now is that its saying the answer is incorrect even though it isnt. It knows the answer is detail[6] because it says thats the correct answer it just doesnt seem to be checking the inputted answer against it?

Comment: @MilanLad I would advice you to implement these fixes and then ask a new question for that. It's hard to know what's wrong because we can't see the changes you've made.

Comment: @MilanLad no problem! Feel free to mark my answer as accepted if you feel like it answered your question :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening the file 10 times, get 10 questions from it and loop asking them:

```
def get_questions(fn, number):
    with open(fn) as f:

        # remove empty lines and string the \n from it - else you get 
        # A\n as last split-value - and your comparisons wont work
        # because A\n != A
        q = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines() if x.strip()]
    random.shuffle(q)
    return q[:number]


def quiz():
    i = 0 
    global score # makes the score variable global so it can be used outside of the function
    score=0 # defines the score variable as '0'

    q = get_questions('space_quiz_test.txt', 10) # gets 10 random questions
    for question in q:
        detail = question.split(",")
        print(detail[0],detail[1],detail[2],detail[3],detail[4],detail[5])
        print(" ")
        # etc ....
```

Doku:

- [inplace list shuffling: `random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle)

---

There are several other things to fix:

```
# global score  # not needed, simply return the score from quiz():
my_score = quiz() # now my_score holds the score that you returned in quiz()
...

# logic errors - but that part can be deleted anyway:
elif detail[0] in qno is True:       # why `is True`? `elif detail[0] in qno:` is enough
    if detail[0] not in qno == True:    # you just made sure that `detail[0]` is in it

... 


 while True:
        answer=input("Answer: ").upper()           # make it upper once here
        if answer not in ('A','B','C','D'):        # and remove the .upper() downstream
            print("Answer not valid, try again")
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by drawing the questions all at once with choice without replacement, then iterating over those.

```
import numpy as np
quiz=open('space_quiz_test.txt').read().splitlines() #opens the file containing the questions, reads it and then splits the lines to make them seperate entities
questions=np.random.choice(quiz, size=10, replace=False)
    for question in quesions: #creates a loop that makes the program print 10 questions
         #rest of your code
```

Comment: Opps, I usually use numpy. Edited.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't think of that. I have the luxury of usually working with pretty short and fast scripts. Should I change to `from numpy import random`? in that case? Or even `from numpy.random import choice `?

Answer (score 1):

Read all the questions:

```
with open('space_quiz_test.txt') as f:
    quiz = f.readlines()
```

Shuffle the list of questions in place:

```
random.shuffle(quiz)
```

Loop on the shuffled list:

```
for question in quiz:
    print(question)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `random.choice` can give the same output more than once. Instead of using random.choice try 
`random.shuffle(list)` and then choosing the first 10 records from the shuffled list.

```
quiz=open('space_quiz_test.txt').read().splitlines()
random.shuffle(quiz)
for question in quiz[1:11]:
        detail = question.split(",")
        print(detail[0],detail[1],detail[2],detail[3],detail[4],detail[5])
```